# Throwing an exception: MissingPluginException, when trying to pick file to upload on Firestore

Tags: flutter, filepicker

I am writing a code to upload pdf file to Firebase Storage and used the package: FilePicker but it is throwing an error when trying to pick the file. I have already tried `flutter clean` and rebuilding the project.

**Error**

```
I/flutter (30101): [MethodChannelFilePicker] Unsupported operation. 
Method not found. The exception thrown was: 
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method any on channel miguelruivo.flutter.plugins.filepicker)
        

 E/flutter (30101): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled 
Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method any on channel 
miguelruivo.flutter.plugins.filepicker)
```

**My code to pick the file**

```
final result=await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
if(result==null){
  return;
}else{
  setState(() {
    PlatformFile pdfFile=result.files.first;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you face an exception `MissingPluginException` the reason is not fully builded project. It means you have added some dependency in your `pubspec.yaml file` and you didn't rebuild your project. Try to stop and run it. Also you can try to do `flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter run` if stop/start not helps.

Comment: I have already tried these, this is not resolving the issue

Answer (score 0):

some times if you add a plugin in yaml file when it is running it will happen.

try to stop the app.

then -> `Flutter clean` then -> `flutter pub get` then run you project.

Comment: I have already tried these, this is not resolving the issue

Comment: are you using real device or simulator?

Comment: I am using the Real Device